# Showing that a function is primitive recursive

Tags: computability

I am given three primitive recursive functions $f$,$g$ and $r$ and I am asked to show that the following functions are primitive recursive:

\begin{equation}
h(x) =
\begin{cases}
f(x) & \text{  if r(x) = 0} \\
 g(x) & \text{if r(x)} \neq 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
t(x) = \# \{ y \leq x : f(y) < y \}
\end{equation}

I don't really understand how to prove that a function is primitive recursive when these are not basic functions or when they are not composition of basic functions so I don't really know how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: you've forgotten recursion.  $h$ can be defined from $f$ and $g$ by recursion. You can then use recursion again and something like $h$ with a suitable choice of $f$, $g$ and $r$ to define $t$.